# Como funcionam os sistemas de hospedagem de sites?

Tags: terminologia

Estou criando um site e gostaria de hospedá-lo, mas tenho algumas dúvidas pois já ouvi dizer que as hospedagens possuem limites de acesso mensal ou limites no de tamanho dos bancos de dados. Portanto gostaria de saber:

**1:** Quais são os tipos de limitações que uma hospedagem comum tem (ou algumas limitações que podem ser considerados na hora de fazer a escolha certa)?

**2:** O que é hospedagem compartilhada?

**3:** O que é exatamente a largura de banda que falam tanto?

**4:** Qual o preço médio de uma boa hospedagem?

**5:** Requerimentos por `AJAX` influenciam nos limites da hospedagem, sendo que os requerimentos serão feitos via `json` para o meu banco de dados?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos lá:

1: Quais são os tipos de limitações que uma hospedagem comum tem (ou algumas limitações que podem ser considerados na hora de fazer a escolha certa)?
R = principalmente tráfego mensal, quantidade de views ou mesmo banda.

2: O que é hospedagem compartilhada?
R = A hospedagem compartilhada tem limitações de CPU e de recursos de hardware para todos os sites. Basicamente, é um servidor compartilhado por diversos sites. Tem uma relação custo/benefício mais interessante.

3: O que é exatamente a largura de banda que falam tanto?
R = largura de banda é a medição de dados, a velocidade com que eles fluem através das linhas de telefone, cabo ou DSL para tranferir informações de e para um site através do seu computador. Em relação a sua hospedagem de site, a largura de banda mede esse fluxo de transferência de dados, é o número de visitas que você recebe em seu site; volume puro multiplicado pelo tamanho do arquivo incluído em suas páginas.

Então, se você tem um site todo o texto baseado na web, você seria capaz de receber mais tráfego, em números menores de largura de banda que você faria se tivesse uma página com muitas imagens e gráficos, o que naturalmente têm tamanhos maiores de arquivos que estão sendo transferidos a partir do seu site para o navegador do seu visitante (http://webartigos.com/artigos/largura-de-banda-e-a-hospedagem-de-sites/65369)

4: Qual o preço médio de uma boa hospedagem?
R = Depende de quais serviços vc contrata. Por exemplo: contas de e-mail, banco de dados, alguma tecnologia de server side(como PHP, Python, Java ou outra). Os preços variam enormemente

5: Requerimentos por AJAX influenciam nos limites da hospedagem, sendo que os requerimentos serão feitos via json para o meu banco de dados?
R = Certamente, influenciarão na largura de banda.

Answer (score 3):

> Quais são os tipos de limitações que uma hospedagem comum tem (ou algumas limitações que podem ser considerados na hora de fazer a escolha certa)?

Em geral há os limites óbvios de espaço em disco que pode ocupar, quanto de tráfego (bytes transferidos pela rede em entrada ou saída) que pode gerar, quanto pode usar em bancos de dados, quantas contas de e-mail e o espaço total ou de cada conta que pode ocupar, quais as tecnologias pode usar, instalar, se pode acessar por que tipo de terminal ou protocolo de acesso e coisas assim.

Há os limites que ninguém fala. Pode haver limite explícito de uso de processador e quantidade de acessos em disco e coisas assim. Em geral isto é discriminado em nuvem, mas não em hospedagens tradicionais. Algumas limitem fisicamente mesmo através de máquinas virtuais ou mecanismo de componentização. Muitas vezes não te contam isso, ou fazem parecer que isto é algo bom para você quando na verdade é limitação.

> O que é hospedagem compartilhada?

Vários sites de vários clientes estão no mesmo servidor. Com isto precisa ter menos flexibilidade, mais limitação, você disputa recursos com os outros e tem uma certa insegurança. Hoje melhorado um pouco com os *dockers* da vida, mas que acaba criando outras dificuldades.

> O que é exatamente a largura de banda que falam tanto?

É a quantidade total de dados que pode passar na rede por um período de tempo, em geral em cada segundo. Então a largura de de 100Mbps pode passar 100 milhões de bits por segundo (o que não é o mesmo de 12,5 milhões de bytes por segundo, como muita gente pensa. Isto é o mesmo que o seu sistema de internet limita. Existe a banda garantida onde você sempre poderá trafegar tudo isto ou a compartilhada onde você disputa tudo isto com outras pessoas.

Isto não limita diretamente quantas visitas seu site pode ter, a não ser que a largura seja muito, muito baixa, o que não existe. Claro que sempre haverá um limite, mas é mais comum o limite ser do servidor e não da largura de banda. É possível entupir uma banda bem larga com apenas uma visita, ainda que raro, e tem mecanismo para não criar problemas em casos assim.

> Qual o preço médio de uma boa hospedagem?

Isso muda, e não dá para responder aqui.

> Requerimentos por AJAX influenciam nos limites da hospedagem, sendo que os requerimentos serão feitos via json para o meu banco de dados?

Certamente, em geral até podem reduzir o uso em comparação com páginas normais, se tudo for feito certo. Conheço quem conseguiu piorar.